# Rails Faker - How to generate a custom domain email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, faker

Ideally I want to create a fake email based on the Faker generated email, but I want to achieve something like: `faker_first_name@mydomain.com`. The documentation shows you can do it for the first part but not the actual domain. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
20.times do
  u = User.new(first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,               
               last_name:  Faker::Name.last_name,
               email: Faker::Name.first_name"@THISPART.com",
               )
  u.save
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just missed the string concat: `+`

```
 :006 > Faker::Name.first_name+"@THISPART.com"
 => "Irving@THISPART.com"
```

And if you meant keeping the same name, save it before:

```
fn = Faker::Name.first_name
sn = Faker::Name.last_name

u = User.create(
          :forename => fn,
          :surname => sn,
          :email => "#{fn}.#{sn}@yourdomain.net",
```

`Faker::Name.first_name` will always generate a new random value.

Answer (score 11):

**Update Dec 2019:**

Faker version v2.8.0 introduced the domain support - [Release v2.8.0](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/releases/tag/v2.8.0)

Now, It is possible to pass the domain while creating the email address.

Following are the possible options:

```
Faker::Internet.email #=> "eliza@mann.net"
Faker::Internet.email(name: 'Nancy') #=> "nancy@terry.biz"
Faker::Internet.email(name: 'Janelle Santiago', separators: '+') #=> janelle+santiago@becker.com"
Faker::Internet.email(domain: 'example.com') #=> alice@example.com"
```

*Note: Above code sample is from the faker documentation*

**Old Answer:**

Well there is no such provision to pass `domain name` to the method

But, you can make use of `Faker::Internet.user_name`

```
User.new(
  first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,               
  last_name:  Faker::Name.last_name,
  email:      "#{Faker::Internet.user_name}@customdomain.com"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Faker has a built in support for custom email subdomains.

```rb
Faker::Internet.email(domain: 'customdomain.com')
```